# Connecting google plus fanpage with website +1 button

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I recently created a fanpage to my site and added a +1 button to it.

I would like to connect my +1 button on my website to the +1 button on my fanpage. I mean - when you +1 in my website and the link you +1 is of the website, it will also add +1 in my google's fanpage.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Google+ Direct Connect](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/). It was recently launched and last I heard the merging of the +1 counts may take some time.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible. After all, you're supposed to +1 the page you're on. Imgaine, if it were possible, people could "plant" +1s for unrelated sites everywhere.

For example, my blog could have a +1 for a NSFW site, which you'd be effectively and **publicly** +1'ing if you click on my website's button.

Comment: They could make system to secure it. for example - if you want to connect website and fan page +1, u need to verify that you are the owner of the site by adding something to its HTML and limit it to one site for each page...